# Size of image for UIcontrol such as UIImageView or UIButton with autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint, uicontrol, ui-design

I have a question that many people find trivial,but still want to get information regarding it.So my scenario is I have a image view with fixed height and width is kept dynamic by pinning it to edges's of the screen,now with screen size width of image view is going to change,so how can I decide size of image that will be used in UIImageView as width is dynamic.

Comment: It will depend on which content mode you have selected - aspect fit, aspect fill, etc

Comment: sorry for delayed reply,as my requirement is to fill all the area of image view,without distorting it.AutoLayout will change size of image view dynamically depend upon current size,so how can i get image of specific size so distortion will not happen.